# Scan and label mac addresses on local network with web interface (similar to fing)

Tags: networking, linux

I really like the [fing app on android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en_US) (app that brute force scans all ips on the local network then port scans to see what services are active) and I was wondering if there was something similar that could be installed on a Raspberry pi.

The use case for me with this is I want to do a quick scan of my network to find headless IoT devices on my phone without needing to login to my router (password is long, difficult to navigate on mobile).

I like being able to assign nicknames to mac addresses to quickly exclude devices that are not new. I know about nmap/Zenmap but couldn't really find much of the latter for Raspberry pi (or a web interface for it). Ideally I'd just bookmark the static route and port to rpi0w serving application, hit scan button, and have a look at what the local/active IPs are.

Main reason I'm looking now is that with latest [Android](https://help.fing.com/knowledge-base/will-fing-app-work-android-10/) and [iOS](https://help.fing.com/knowledge-base/cant-fing-see-mac-addresses-ios-11/), access to MAC addresses have been disallowed so I would need to root my phone to have the same functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: How you have connected to the Raspberry Pi Zero W? I mean, you want a package with GUI or just working on the terminal?

Comment: i have a little hdmi monitor and keyboard attached to it currently, could also ssh in, would prefer web interface so i could just pin it on android desktop

Comment: Angry IP scanner is one of the best tools for you but it released just for amd64 and x86 architecture. You need an armhf/arm64 architecture. Maybe you would able to run it on the raspberry pi but I think it's not reasonable. However, you can do it easily by `nmap`/`zenmap`.